# Firestore Security Rules "exists()” with Query Permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

It appears that Firestore queries do not work well with the subcollections data structure.

My database is structured like this:

```
users
  userUid
    { userData }
  ...
groups
  groupID
    { groupData }
    members
      member1uid
        { memberData }
      ...
    messages
      message1
        { messageData }
      ...
```

And my rules for testing if a user is a member of a certain group is like this:

```
function isMemberOfGroup(groupId) {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)/members/$(request.auth.uid))
}

match /groups/{groupId} {
  allow read: if isMemberOfGroup(groupId)
}
```

The problem is that I cannot use queries with these rules because there is no way (that I have found) to query based on whether a subcollection contains a certain document. This means that I cannot list all of the groups that a certain user is a member of. I tried just listing all of the users in a map that is part of the `groupData` but I cannot set permissions on who can edit certain parts of a document so that won't work either.

**EDIT:**
From what I understand the query must match the rule in some way or else permission will be denied. How would I go about creating a query that collects all groups that a certain user is in and fulfills this rule.

Comment: I'm not clear on what isn't working the way you expect. Do you have a particular snippet of code - a specific use case?  Also it would be nice to see a complete set of rules, not just one function.  Code and rules always go together.

Comment: @DougStevenson I keep getting `Missing or insufficient permissions` and I am not even sure what to try.

Comment: What query would you use, assuming that security rules allowed all access?  It's not clear to me from what you've shown.  Bear in mind that your database structure might not be suitable for both the query and the rules you'd like to use.

Comment: @DougStevenson Given all access `firebase.firestore().collection('groups').get()` should work, I just don't know what to put for `.where()` that matches the rule.

Comment: It sounds like you should rephrase the question in terms of trying to get the data that you want, rather than a problem with security rules.  I recommend getting the data model and query settled first, then worry about security rules.

Comment: A read like `firebase.firestore().collection('groups').get()` will never work if members should only be able to reader groups that they're a member of. Firebase security rules don't filter data on their own. Instead they determine what read operations/queries are allowed. So you will always have to replicate the "members only" logic in a query, which is only possible if the data about membership is in the document itself (since a single query/read can only read from a single collection/group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase security rules don't filter data on their own. Instead they determine what read operations/queries are allowed.

So a read like `firebase.firestore().collection('groups').get()` will never work if members should only be able to read groups that they're a member of.

You will always have to replicate the "members only" logic in the query. This is only possible if the data about membership is in the document itself, since a single query/read can only read from a single collection/group. Since in your data structure the data that authorization depends on is in a different collection, I don't think you can securely query it, although you **can** secure access to individual documents.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand that security tules don't filter data, I was just trying to understand how to query the data in a way that matched the rules. I decided to use collection groups instead and query the `members` collections by user id and get the parent document.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that the query logic must contain data within the document, it isn't possible for the rules of a collection to check custom claims from a users token and still be able to query that collection?

Comment: If you can put the information in custom claims that can work within security rules. You just can query other documents (though you can `get()` them) through a sort of JOIN like construct.